# How to pass two objects of different class to the View's model

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, viewbag

In `Details` view of a Person I would like to also display also other objects from the `DbContext`, every record of table `Survey` to be exact. So I inserted them into `ViewBag`

Person's controller action:

```
   [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult _Survey1(int id) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("PASSED ID: " + id);
            Person person = db.Persons.Find(id);
            ViewBag.Surveys = db.Surveys.ToList();//HERE I insert Surveys to ViewBag
            return PartialView(person);
        }
```

and try to iterate over them in View :

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.Person
<hr />
<h2>Survey</h2>

<input type="button" id="Coll" value="Collapse" onclick="javascript:CollapseDiv()" />
<p>
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => ViewBag.Surveys.Count)
</p>
@foreach (var survey in ViewBag.Surveys) {
    <p>
        @using (Html.BeginForm()) {

            <text>ANK</text>
            @Html.DisplayFor(x => survey.Questions.Count)
            @Html.EditorFor(x => survey.Questions) 
            <input type="submit" />
        }
    </p>
}

<hr />
```

The problem is that I get:

[image]

**Question:**  As tschmit007 suggested how to define model which can take `Person` and `IEnumerable and pass data to it?

Comment: `@Html.DisplayFor(x => ViewBag.Surveys.Count)` expects you to use a part of the model, what do you want that to generate? A field populated with the count?

Comment: @siva.k I want to display number of rows in table `Survey`. If I was in controller I would write `db.Surveys.Count` instead of `ViewBag.Surveys.Count`.

Comment: edit your model: Add a `IEnumerable<Survey> Surveys` to it; keep strongly typed views.

Comment: @tschmit007 how to add another field to the model? Could you show me how model in the View should look and how to pass this additional controller?

Comment: well you edit the `WebApplication2\Models\Person.cs` file. Add the property, then populate it at the controller level. That is you create a ViewModel as suggested by CodeCaster.

Comment: @tschmit007 I know only how to pass one object to the model, how to pass also `IEnumerable<Survey> Surveys` to it without losing a `Person`?

Comment: @tschmit007 How to pass it as a `Tuple`?

Comment: for example, or as a `new class PersonModel { Person Person {get; set;} IEnumerable<Survey> Surveys {get; set;}}`. Then you edit your cshtml to `@model WebApplication2.Models.PersonModel`, and fix the cshtml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a view model that includes properties for `Person` and `Surveys`.For example

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  public Person Person { get; set; } // or create properties for each property or Person
  public IEnumerable<Survey> Surveys { get; set; }
}
```

When displaying the page

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Details (int ID)
{
  MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel();
  model.Person = db.Persons.Find(id);
  model.Surveys = db.Surveys;
  return View(model);
}
```

and in the view

```
@model YourAssembly.MyViewModel

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Person.SomeProperty) // display properties of person

@foreach (var survey in Model.Surveys) {
  @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.EditorFor(x => survey.Questions) 
        <input type="submit" />
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is great answer! But I also posted an answer a second approach which I used yesterday. I used a `Tuple`.

Answer (score 1):

I passed data as a Tuple without creating a ViewModel. Tuple showed up in .NET 4.0. This did the job:

```
 public ActionResult _Survey1(int id) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("PASSED ID: " + id);
            Person person = db.Persons.Find(id);
            var tuple = new Tuple<Person,  List<Survey>>(person, db.Surveys.ToList()){};               
            return PartialView(tuple);
        }
```

---

```
@using WebApplication2.Models
@model   System.Tuple<Person, List<Survey>>

<hr />
<h2>Surveys</h2>

<input type="button" id="Coll" value="Collapse" onclick="javascript:CollapseDiv()" />
<p>
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.Item2.Count)
</p>

@foreach (var survey in Model.Item2) {
    using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        <text>Number of Questions in a Survey</text>
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => survey.Questions.Count)
        <p/>
        @Html.EditorFor(x => survey.Questions)
        <input type="submit" />
    }

}
<hr />
```

Answer (score 0):

`@Html.DisplayFor(x => ViewBag.Surveys.Count)` expects you to use a part of the model where you have `ViewBag` should be `x`. What you need to do is to drop the `For` which makes it not use the model.

Instead use:

```
@Html.Display(ViewBag.Surveys.Count) 

@Html.Display(survey.Questions.Count)
@Html.Editor(survey.Questions)
```

The `Display` ones can most likely be excluded all together:

```
<p>@ViewBag.Surveys.Count</p>
```

Will also work.

Comment: There is a problem with those helper methods: http://s15.postimg.org/xwbvonwez/image.png

Comment: @Yoda what `type` is `survey.Questions`? If it's not a `string` it won't work, you'll have to break it out into it's individual fields.

Comment: @Yoda it might work a lot better for you to split this out into a partial view instead of passing via `ViewBag` anyway as there can be some performance hits if you're passing around a bunch of data via `ViewBag`.

Comment: `Questions` are `ICollection<Question> Ok, so how to define model which has one field `Person` and second `IEnumerable<Survey>`?

Comment: It is already a partial I want to pass `Person` and `IEnumberable<Survey>` to the object.

Comment: Please look at my controller action I get Person's id then find a Person and get Surveys then I want to pass it to the model. In your update there is no mentioning of Person and there is only one thing passed to the View.

Comment: @Yoda You can only ever pass one model into a view. If you need to pass more data then your model has you need to either 1) make a new model that contains all relevant data, or 2) extend your current primary model to include the relevant data.